# What is match status and turn status when a game expire in Android google play service?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

Example :

Participants : player1 and player2

last updater : player1

player2 has not respond for two weeks.

What would be match status and players status?

Answer (score 0):

After two weeks, the match should expire. In this case **player** status should be [`STATUS_UNRESPONSIVE`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch#MATCH_STATUS_EXPIRED) and **match** status should be [`MATCH_STATUS_EXPIRED`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Participant#STATUS_UNRESPONSIVE).

You can refer to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#tracking_match_expiration) for more details.

Comment: [`MATCH_RESULT_DISCONNECT`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/ParticipantResult.html#MATCH_RESULT_DISCONNECT) seems pretty likely.